# How do I call a procedure in MySQL that has a cursor and applies to all rows?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

Below I have the code for the DDL and the procedure. I want to apply this procedure on the visit column of the relation. My goal is to modify the date format to mm/dd/yyyy format.
How would I call the function? to be more specific how do I pass the input of the visit column to the procedure?

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
patno VARCHAR(3), -- patient number (3 digits)
gender VARCHAR(1), -- gender ('M' or 'F')
visit VARCHAR(10), -- visit date (MM/DD/YYYY)

INSERT INTO patient VALUES ('001','m','11/11/1998',88,140,80,'1','0');
INSERT INTO patient VALUES ('002','f','11/13/1998',84,120,78,'X','0');
INSERT INTO patient VALUES ('003','1','10/21/1998',68,190,100,'3','1');
INSERT INTO patient VALUES ('004','F','01/01/1999',101,200,120,'5','A');
```

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE change_date()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE patno_var VARCHAR(3);
    DECLARE visit_var VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE daynr varchar(2);
    DECLARE monthnr varchar(2);
    DECLARE yearnr varchar(4);
    DECLARE temp varchar(2);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT patno, visit FROM project33.patient;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO patno_var, visit_var;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        /*split the visit col*/
        SET daynr = SUBSTRING(visit_var, 1, 2);
        SET monthnr = SUBSTRING(visit_var, LOCATE('/', visit_var, 2) + 1, 2);
        SET yearnr = SUBSTRING(visit_var, LOCATE('/', visit_var, 5) + 1, 4);

        /*fix the vars */
        IF monthnr > 12 THEN 
            SET temp = monthnr;
            SET monthnr = daynr;
            SET daynr = temp;


       ELSEIF monthnr IN (01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12) AND daynr > 31 THEN
            SET daynr = (daynr - 31);
            SET monthnr = (monthnr + 1);
  
        
       ELSEIF monthnr IN (04, 06, 09, 11) AND daynr > 30 THEN
            SET daynr = (daynr - 30);
            SET monthnr = (monthnr + 1);
        END IF;

        SET visit_var = CONCAT(monthnr, '/', daynr, '/', yearnr);
        
        /* update the visit column using the primary key */
        UPDATE patient SET visit = visit_var WHERE patno = patno_var;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Then I called the function as

```
call change_date();
```

This gives me error operand should contain 1 columns

Comment: Please provide necessary table structure and sample data, as your procedure queries table `project33.pat_clean` and inserts into `pat_clean.dateofvisit`. By the way, I believe your 3 `IF monthnr` statements should be parallel, not serial. I would put them all in a single `if` statement using `elseif` .

Comment: You have published a table patient which fails a synrax check and is not used in the procedure, a table pat_clean which is used by the cursor but not published , a table dateofvistit which is inserted to but not published and you have used parameter names which are the same as column names(which is a bad thing if patient is indeed used)

Comment: Furthermore, your procedure has an IN parameter `visit` which is passed to your /*split the visit col*/ part. But that part also requires an IN parameter `date_mod` from the procedure, which i suppose you erroneously set to `OUT` .

Comment: And the insert to patient has more columns than in the published table..Please revisit the question..

Comment: @blabla_bingo i have updated my procedure code in my question and now with this updated code I can call it with CALL change_date(); I also took ur advice and changed it to IFELSE statements. Although this procedure works for a date such as 15/12/1999 now, it does not work for 08/32/1998 (nothing changes). To my understanding, the ifelse block should take care of this, do u have any idea what might be going on there? Thanks again for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

In your /*fix the vars */ part,if monthnr > 12 THEN month and day values are swapped based on your 3 `SET` statements. However, at the end of the procedure,the `SET visit_var = CONCAT(monthnr, '/', daynr, '/', yearnr);` statement swap the position of month and day in the string (contrary to the day/month/year format in the base table), which means nothing changes for those `monthnr > 12`. Let's remove that part for now to demonstrate the logic but you will need it later.

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
patno VARCHAR(3), -- patient number (3 digits),
visit VARCHAR(10) -- visit date (MM/DD/YYYY)
);

INSERT INTO patient VALUES 
 ('005','15/12/1999'),
 ('006','08/32/1998')
 ;
 
 DELIMITER //
drop procedure if exists change_date//
CREATE PROCEDURE change_date()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE patno_var VARCHAR(3);
    DECLARE visit_var VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE daynr varchar(2);
    DECLARE monthnr varchar(2);
    DECLARE yearnr varchar(4);
    DECLARE temp varchar(2);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT patno, visit FROM project33.patient;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO patno_var, visit_var;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        /*split the visit col*/
        SET daynr = SUBSTRING(visit_var, 1, 2);
        SET monthnr = SUBSTRING(visit_var, LOCATE('/', visit_var, 2) + 1, 2);
        SET yearnr = SUBSTRING(visit_var, LOCATE('/', visit_var, 5) + 1, 4);

        /* let's remove this monthnr > 12 part for now but later on you'll find it necessary later on
        IF monthnr > 12 THEN 
            SET temp = monthnr; -- 32
            SET monthnr = daynr; -- 8
            SET daynr = temp; -- 32
            */

       IF monthnr IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) AND daynr > 31 THEN
            SET daynr = (daynr - 31);
            SET monthnr = (monthnr + 1);
  
        
       ELSEIF monthnr IN (4, 6, 9, 11) AND daynr > 30 THEN
            SET daynr = (daynr - 30);
            SET monthnr = (monthnr + 1);
        END IF;
    
  
    
        SET visit_var = CONCAT(monthnr, '/', daynr, '/', yearnr);
        
    
        /* update the visit column using the primary key */
        UPDATE patient SET visit = visit_var WHERE patno = patno_var;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
END //
DELIMITER ;

-- begin the test
select * from patient;
+-------+------------+
| patno | visit      |
+-------+------------+
| 005   | 15/12/1999 |
| 006   | 08/32/1998 |
+-------+------------+

 call change_date;

select * from patient;
+-------+------------+
| patno | visit      |
+-------+------------+
| 005   | 12/15/1999 |
| 006   | 32/08/1998 |
+-------+------------+
```

The value has been changed. However, a date value of '32/08/1998' is hardly appropriate. That's why I said  the `if monthnr > 12` part in the procedure is necessary. You don't neet to swap the values for month and day,but you certainly need to put a condition check such as `if monthnr >31 then ...`
Last but not least, to make certain your data values are eligible, consider using `str_to_date` function to do a format check before updating the table.

```
 SET visit_var = str_to_date(CONCAT(monthnr, '/', daynr, '/', yearnr),'%c/%e/%Y');
```